# Enter Parameter Value Dialog Box Comes Up When I Run Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have created a Crystal report that is using a query which UNION two tables. The second table does not have the same amount of rows as the first one, thus I am passing null values for those fields.

The report shows correct data, but when I run it, it asks me to enter values for these null field in the Enter Parameter Windows.

Below is the code and the image of what I get. Any idea how to fix this.
**(the query shown is the one below the UNION)**

```
SELECT  ncs.staff_id,
    substring(service_code, 7) as Service_Value,
    substring(replace(replace(service_code,'(',''), ')', ''), 1, 3) as Service_Code,
    duration,
    service_date,
    null as PATID,
    scd.name as Staff_Name,
    CASE substring(replace(replace(service_code,'(',''), ')', ''), 1, 3)
            WHEN '703' then 'NB'
            WHEN '704' then 'NB'
            WHEN '709' then 'NB'
            WHEN '710' then 'NB'
            WHEN '900' then 'NB'
            WHEN '826' THEN 'NB'
            WHEN '827' THEN 'NB'
            WHEN '406' THEN 'NB'
            WHEN '708' THEN 'NB'
            WHEN '564' THEN 'NB'
            WHEN '707' THEN 'NB'
            WHEN '211' THEN 'NB'
            WHEN '399' THEN 'NB'
            WHEN '702' THEN 'NB'
            WHEN '705' THEN 'NB'
            WHEN '723' THEN 'NB'
            END AS Charge_Cat,

    null as episode_number,
    null as patient_name,
    start_time as start_time,
    cast(dateadd(MINUTE,  duration,start_time)as time ) as end_time,
    ncs.ID,
    null as guarantor_id,
    null as guarantor_name,
    'I' as Service_Code,
    scd.practitioner_category_value,
    null as RRG_CODE, --RRG NEED TO CHECK IF IT IS POSIBLE TO CREATE A VALUE BASE ON PROGRAM CODE
    null as Join_to_tx_history,
    ncs.FACILITY,
    null as location_value,
    substring(replace(replace(service_program,'(',''), ')', ''), 1, 3) as Program_Code,
    substring(service_program, 7)

FROM    NON_CLIENT_SPECIFIC_ENTRY ncs
        INNER JOIN staff_current_demographics scd ON
        scd.FACILITY = ncs.FACILITY AND scd.STAFFID = ncs.STAFF_ID
WHERE service_date BETWEEN {?fDate} AND {?toDate}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it asks me to enter values for these null fields"? It should ask you to supply values for `{?fDate}` and `{?toDate}`, but the nulls have nothing to do with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

When the report was changed to use a query instead of tables, it deleted all references for the sub report links. Creating them again and changing the code in the sub report selection expert to use the new created linked parameters fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this one is that when the changes were made the reference for the subreport links were also deleted or the new names did not match the previous ones. So it was asking me to enter values for the sub report linked parameters.

I updated the subreport links and substituted the old names with the new ones